# TikZ: circle split vertical

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I want to split a TikZ node into a left and a right part, just like `circle split` does in upper and lower part, e.g.

`\node [circle split,draw] (x){$a$ \nodepart{lower} $b$}`

Is there a vertical equivalent, e.g.

`\node [circle split vertical,draw] (x){$a$ \nodepart{right} $b$}`?

---

Here is an example of a node which is split **horizontally**, however I would like the split to be **vertical**:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [circle split,draw] (z){$a$ \nodepart{lower} $b$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX and please post complete examples so that we don't search for the required pieces.

Comment: I added a small but complete example for horizontal splitting of a node.

Comment: @user56059: what about rotation (with `shape border rotate`)?

Comment: Worst case... you can do it manually: `\node [circle,draw,text width=1.5em] (z){$a$ \hfill $b$};
\draw (z.north) -- (z.south);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: split]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [circle split,draw,rotate=90] (z){\rotatebox{-90}{$a$} \nodepart{lower} \rotatebox{-90}{$b$}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ends up very large and my text is on uneven lines.

Comment: @liridayn  - The centers are aligned.  Add a \strut to each to make them the same size.  You can reduce the size of the node by reducing [inner sep].

Answer (score 4):

This solution uses PGF 3.0.0 `pic` new feature, to define a new pic element named `node vertically split` which receives two parameters which are the contents of the left and right parts. It also defines names to the parts of the pic which allow to later add different kind of connections, as it is shown in the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
    pics/circle vertically split/.style 2 args = {
       code = {
         \node[inner sep=3pt,left] (-left) {#1};
         \node[inner sep=3pt,right] (-right) {#2};
         \path let
              \p1 = ($(-left.north west) - (-left.east)$),
              \p2 = ($(-right.west) - (-right.south east)$),
              \n1 = {max(veclen(\p1), veclen(\p2))*2}
           in node[minimum size=\n1, circle, draw] (-shape) at (0,0) {};
         \draw (-shape.north) -- (-shape.south);
       }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0)  pic (A) {circle vertically split={$a$}{$b$}}
      (2,2)  pic (B) {circle vertically split={Hello}{World}}
      (2,-1) pic (C) {circle vertically split={Hello}{$b$}};

\draw[->, blue]  (A-shape) -- (B-shape);
\draw[blue, dotted] (C-shape.north east) -- (B-shape.south east);
\draw[->, red]   (A-right) to[out=0,in=90] (C-right.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\def\size{2 }

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-\size,-\size)(\size,\size)
  \pswedge{\size}{90}{270}
  \rput(!-\size 2 div 0){\Huge $a$}
  \pswedge{\size}{270}{90}
  \rput(!\size 2 div 0){\Huge $b$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]