# How to find why it stopped compiling (Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function)

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, compiling

I have created vertically split circle and it works standalone but it stop when I add this code to my [university template](https://github.com/Ashymad/aghdpl-imir). Here is standalone code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% BEGIN section 1 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning,fit}
% END section 1
\begin{document}
% BEGIN section 2
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tikzset{
    pics/circle vertically split/.style 2 args = {
       code = {
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\widthOne}{width("#1")+4pt}
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\widthTwo}{width("#2")+4pt}

         \node[text=green](-this_is_currcent_center){+};
         \node[xshift=-\widthOne/2] (-left) {#1};
         \node[xshift=\widthTwo/2] (-right) {#2};
         \node[fit=(-left)(-right),draw,circle,text=red](-shape) {+};
         \node(-splitline) at ($ (-left.east)!.5!(-right.west) $) {};
         \draw (-shape.north east -| -splitline.center) -- (-shape.south east -| -splitline.center);
       }
    }
}
% this doesn't center correctly but it's not part of this question
\pic[inner sep = 1pt, align=left] (A) {circle vertically split={$Aaaaaa$}{$B$}};
\pic[inner sep = 1pt, align=left, right = of A-shape] (B) {circle vertically split={A}{$Bbbbb$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
% END section 2
\end{document}
```

Standalone code produce:
[image: result of standalone code]

Error after adding to university template:

> ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `Aaaaaa' (in
>   'width(""Aaaaaa"")+4pt' ).

### How to reproduce error

For anyone who want to help me I created a quick way to repoduce error in 30s:

1. Clone repository (this is fork of template) --`git clone https://github.com/xoac/aghdpl-imir.git`
2. Checkout to branch split-circle -- `git checkout split-circle`
3. Compile with command `latexmk -outdir=build -pdf praca.tex`

#### Additional information:

Check difference between raw template and after my changes `git diff master split-circle`

`pdflatex --version`:

> pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux) kpathsea
>   version 6.3.1
>   Copyright 2019 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al. There is NO
>   warranty.  Redistribution of this software is covered by the terms of
>   both the pdfTeX copyright and the Lesser GNU General Public License.
>   For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING
>   and the pdfTeX source.
>   Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh
>   (pdfTeX) et al.
>   Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
>   Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
>   Compiled with poppler version 0.85.0

---

**How can I find why it stopped compiling after adding my code?**

---

*I create my vertically split circle mixed this two solutions: 
1. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528851/192768
2. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186506/192768*

Comment: PD --- notice that you have mispelled `--version` in your question...

Comment: @Rmano Thank you. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that your format is used with

```
\usepackage[english, polish]{babel}
```

which transforms the meaning of some special char (technically it *makes chars active*), in this case probably the quote `"` which I suppose it is used to add some accent around... (I do not know Polish, so I don't know the details).

If you use utf8 to input special chars, you can try to disable `babel` shorthands with

```
 \usepackage[english, polish, shorthands=off]{babel}
```

or you can try loading the Ti*k*Z library

```
   \usetikzlibrary{babel}
```

I think that both approaches work in your example.

[Problem with babel and tikz using \draw](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw) is very similar to this, I suspect.

Comment: Both answers works. Thanks. Errors are very unintuitive in latex!